# Show dynamic data from MySql into table Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I need to show data from a database in an Android application. The problem is that I don't know (in advance) how many columns the db contains, as they are added/deleted dynamically. Also, I don't know how column headers will be named.

What is the best approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: So if you need to order the data in the android app with all the data you pass from JSON or XML you need to see which keys there are an considering what you need to do with. Are you programming too php/mysql backend? So if you are doing it you can pass a key with a value called type and then order the information using the type reference

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I didn't catch all you said, but yes, I am also developing back-end side with PHP. I searched the web, and in almost every solution I found the answer in which you use:

`code`
for (int i = 0; i <array.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.optJSONObject(i);
            String area = jsonObject.optString("area");
            String city = ...
            list.add(new User(area,city));
        }

Problem is that JSON response keys can change in every moment, like the example above, in next response I can receive totally different keys.

Comment: So think that you are passing the data to the android app. You pass the data know how to make JSON or XML file preview with PHP? So you can pass diferent values by keys. Exemple of a JSON file would be this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVO7Q.png. And XML file would be this:http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/xml/XML_and_PHP_Simplified03/unformattedxmldoc.png So in the first or the second case you can pass too a key called type with value 1 and read the xml response file with a Volley httprequest and when the value of type equals 1 estructure the info in the app as you want

Comment: Response from server is something like this:
[{"id":"1", "name":"John", "surname":"Doe", "age":"32", "address":"unknown"}, {"id":"2", "name":"Michael", "surname":"Johnson", "age":"40", "address":"address 2"}, {"id":"3", "name":"Ann", "surname":"Smith", "age":"28", "address":"some street 5"}, {"id":"4", "name":"Linda", "surname":"Moor", "age":"30", "address":"unknown 130"}]



But keys and values can be different in every other response from server, like:

[{"id":"1", "color":"blue", "hex":"xxxxxx", "rgb":"xxx"}, {"id":"2", "color":"red", "hex":"xxxxxx", "rgb":"xxx"}]

Comment: I understand now I will perfoming a correct answer sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

So understanding that you have a lot of multiple type of responses you can do this:

```
int keys = array.length();
    for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++) { 

    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(n);
//val is the value of the object
     String val = object.toString();

     }
```

For advanced gettings see this answer using GSON lib goo.gl/DZfPwj

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to show data in table or listview, I don't exactly understand how to do this. I can't just go: String name = object.optString("name") - because maybe I have key "color" or something else... Also, how to know which keys are header of a column, and which keys represents data?